# Arguments for and against forcing religious organizations to pay taxes (United States)

Tags: united-states, taxes, religion, first-amendment

In the United States, currently, religious organizations are not required to pay taxes

**The first amendment doesn’t prevent religious organizations from paying taxes, link https://www.freedomforuminstitute.org/first-amendment-center/topics/freedom-of-religion/establishment-clause-overview/tax-exemptions/**

What are some common arguments for and against requiring religious organizations to pay taxes? What is the current political climate on this subject (in the US)? Are there any legal arguments (except ones including the first amendment) for and against this, and if so what are they?

Comment: [The Supreme Court has made clear that a tax exemption is neither prohibited nor required under the First Amendment’s free-exercise and establishment clauses](https://www.freedomforuminstitute.org/first-amendment-center/topics/freedom-of-religion/establishment-clause-overview/tax-exemptions/). There are many political arguments for or against tax exemption for religious organizations, but I don't think they're centered around the 1st Amendment as you argue

Comment: To clarify: are you specifically asking __only__ about 1st Amendment issues related to this, as the body seems to be? Or are you asking about all arguments, as in the title?

Comment: @divibisan I was asking about all arguments, I’ll will clarify in the body. Thank you for pointing that out and thank you for the link.

Comment: This seems not only like it will attract opinion based answers but ones that contradict each other and I don't think it is a good fit for this site.

Comment: Related (but not a dupe): https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2430/what-are-the-arguments-for-and-against-charities-engaging-in-political-campaigni/2436#2436

Comment: @JoeW It is about common arguments, current political climate and possible legal arguments, I don’t see how that is opinion based, I might be wrong.

Comment: Well take the first amendment for example some could argue that it requires religion to be exempt from taxes as to not involve them in government while others could argue that it requires taxes on religion as to not favor them. The problem is that people can argue the same point from different sides with valid arguments making it hard not to say it is an opinion.

Comment: @JoeW yes it could be answered with an opinion, as could nearly everything on this site, but it could also be answered like “some people believe that religions should be exempt from taxes to not be involved in religion, while others believe that there should be taxes on religions to not show favor to them.”

Comment: As Chief Justice John Marshall stated back in 1819, “the power to tax involves the power to destroy.” Keeping churches tax exempt removes the temptation from government to interfere with the free exercise of religion, also guaranteed by the First Amendment. In 1970, the U.S. Supreme Court held that property tax exemptions for churches were in keeping with the Establishment Clause of the First Amendment. (Walz v. Tax Commission)

Comment: @r13 The Walz decision held that tax exemptions were not prohibited by the 1st amendment, despite providing a benefit to religious organizations, not that they were required or encouraged.

Comment: @divisan It is the key to the opponents' (to the exemption) argument that "that giving churches special tax exemptions violates the separation of church and state". Why you continuous to insist it serves no purpose.

Comment: @divisan I consider the OP has no case to raise the question, as the venue for against the exemption has been closed by the US Supreme Court decision in the May 4, 1970, to uphold property tax exemptions for churches, in the 8-1 majority opinion written by Chief Justice Warren E. Burger in Walz v. Tax Commission of the City of New York.

Comment: @divisan I am non-religious person, have no bag of religion, but support the decision of close this post, because the reason was the one I tried to point out unsuccessfully in my previous response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many forms of taxes that an organisation may pay.  There are the income taxes that are taken from its staff's wages, there are sales taxes on items that it buys and sells, there are land taxes on the property it owns and finally, there are taxes on the profit that it makes.  When we talk about an organisation paying taxes we tend to think about the last one, but we should remember that this is only part of the tax contribution that it makes.  In this answer, I use "church" and "pastor" as a shorthand for other religious groups and leaders. So "church" may actually be "temple", "mosque", "synagogue", and "pastor" may mean "iman", "rabbi" etc.

Generally, churches don't pay tax on profit, because they don't make a profit. They don't have shareholders who benefit from the profit of the church.

Churches do usually pay taxes on the wages of their pastors, deacons, bishops and other paid workers for the church.  Pay for pastors is quite low (considering the amount of training that they receive) but it is taxed.

Churches also pay sales taxes, but often are exempt from property tax.  This is because the church building is not a profit-making venue

Insofar as a church is functioning as a charity, it benefits the government not to tax it. The counter-argument is clearly that some "churches" are actually profit-making organisations in disguise, who use the veneer of "religion" as a way to avoid tax. without benefitting their communities.

Comment: Why?  I pay sales taxes.  Am I a profit making venue?

Comment: Churches don't pay sales tax, they present a tax-exempt-organization qualification letter which the merchant makes a copy of, which is then filed when the store forwards tax receipts.

Comment: @JamesK - I think you'd prefer to be making more money than you spend, like most people.  If you have any dependents, they're also hoping to directly benefit from you making money (so they can buy things too, if for no other reason).  You're probably not a venue, though. :)